# Проблема при настройки связи webhook в gitea и сервером

Tags: git, docker, githooks, gitea

У меня стоит задача, что при любом действии с репозиторием в gitea при помощи webhook. Информация о каком-либо действии отправляется на сервер, там она обрабатывается и при помощи телеграм бота отправляется в беседу(тегая заодно человека, который сделал действие).
Сначала думал использовать встроенную интеграцию gitea с telegram для настройки webhook. Но пришёл в ступор, как обрабатывать полученную информацию как я хочу.
Пришлось вернуться к идеи через сервер.
Написал вот такую болванку:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Получены данные:', req.body);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Сервер запущен на порту ${port}`);
});
```

Дальше пошёл создавать webhook. Указал адрес http://localhost:3001/webhook, метод POST, POST Content Type: application/json.

Однако при любом действии с репозиторием, я ничего не получаю, а напротив вебхука в гитеа получаю просто красный треугольник с восклицательным знаком. Пока что нет идей в чем может быть проблема.
Если есть другие варианты решения данной задачи, то пишите - буду рад

Comment: для gitea `http://localhost:3001` реально является тем же хостом?

Comment: @nörbörnën Не совсем понял ваш вопрос. Если вы имели в виду, на каком хосте запущена gitea, то тоже на localhost только на другом портe

Comment: @nörbörnën Ну и да, для уточнения, gitea я запускаю при помощи docker. А сервер(болванку), просто из консоли командой: node index.js

Comment: то есть localhost для gitea находится внутри докера, а не там, где вы запускаете болванку?

Comment: Да, получается так. Я понял, что вы имеет в виду, спасибо. Исправлю и попробую заново.

Comment: Какую ошибку вы получаете? Предоставьте пример как здесь: https://imgur.com/3MeuqXz